# Glassfish Server not in list of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.3.4

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish, application-server

I want to switch from Tomcat to Glassfish for the deployment of my web application.
Unfortunately, the application server Glassfish is not listed in the dialog of my IntelliJ IDE.
[image]
The IntelliJ [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service-on-glassfish-application-server.html) lists Glassfish.
How am I able to add/use it?

- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.3.4
- MacOS 10.13.3

**UPDATE**
I tried previous version of the IDE and with 2017.2.7 Glassfish appears in the list of application servers:
[image]
Does anybody know why IntelliJ IDEs with versions 2017.3.x are missing Glassfish?

Comment: After  a few years, this seems to have reared its head again.  Glassfish does not appear in my list of app servers... and I can find no related plugin about Glassfish.  I'm using Intellij Idea Ultimate 2023.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GlassFish Integration** bundled plugin must be [enabled](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html) in Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Plugins.

Comment: Thanks, after setting up Glassfish with 2017.2.7 and I reopened the project with my original IDE, it suggested to enable the plugin.